# Why is /tmp/go-build644681611/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe passed in to go run

Tags: go

I was playing and learning with the beego framework for go, but my hello world example didn't run and from what I determine is that beego does a chdir based on os.Args[0] and that the program is run there. And that is why the app runs, but can't find the views directory.

So backtracking to a simpler level, filename 'example.go':

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getwd())
    fmt.Println(os.Args[0])
}
```

Will output:

```
/<directory 'go run this_file.go' was run in>/ <nil>
/tmp/go-build178877254/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/example
```

I don't understand enough about go as why this the way it is. My first thought is that I'm using gvm (go version manager) and this is happening because something is off. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Apparently,

1. go build
2. ./example

produces a better, expected, and successful outcome:

```
 <directory './example' was run in>/ <nil>
 <directory './example' was run in>/
```

Comment: Yes, apparently 1. go build and 2. ./built is preferred.

Comment: Don't call your files `test` or have them end with `_test.go` — see here: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing

Comment: eh, that was just an example for here...it was actually gohw.go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`go run`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) will compile ([`go build`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)) your source into the system `TEMP` or `TMP` environment variable, then execute the file from there. It's not *really* designed for the running of production code, as it obviously takes longer to compile and execute than to just execute.

The usual practice is to use `go run` for development, and then `go build` and distribute the binaries. `go run` is really a convenience for the developer to quickly test code in one command. It *does* have some useful benefits in running portable source code between multiple, disparate systems, but, if you're going to deploy the code to all of these systems, it's usually normal to include the `go build` in the deployment. Check out [the full guide to the Go command](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)

To make matters easier, it's quite possible to just [cross-compile](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go) Go code to multiple target architectures on one machine, then just deploy the binaries to the relevant machines. This means that the target systems don't even need Go installed. In addition to the link above, you can check out [goxc](https://github.com/laher/goxc) which provides an even simpler way, single line, cross-compilation tool.